# Почему неправильно работает кэширование?

Tags: php, api

Код

```
<?php
$cache_ttl = 1800; // время жизни кэша в секундах
$cache_file_data = "tmp/data.data";
if (file_exists($cache_file_data) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_data)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные
    $response = file_get_contents($cache_file_data);
} else {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.travelpayouts.com/v2/prices/month-matrix?currency=RUS&origin=MOW&destination=AER&show_to_affiliates=true&month=2017-12-13&token=******");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("X-Access-Token: *******"));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
  file_put_contents($cache_file_data, $response);

}
$data = json_decode($response, true);
?>

<table id="examples" class="display"  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead style="background: steelblue">
<tr>
<th style="color: wheat;">Дата вылета </th>
<th style="color: wheat;">Цена, р.</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
</thead>
 <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Дата вылета </th>
<th>Цена, р.</th>
<th></th>
</tr>
 </tfoot>
<tbody>

<?php 

for ($i=0; $i < 5; $i++) { 
echo"<tr>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['depart_date']  ;
echo"</td>";
echo"<td>";
echo $data['data'][$i]['value']  ;
echo"</td>"; 
echo"<td>";
echo"<a href='/flights/?origin_iata=MOW&destination_iata=AER&depart_date=".$data['data'][$i]['depart_date']."&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&trip_class=0&marker=87111&with_request=true'>Поиск</a>";
echo"</td>"; 
echo"</tr>";
}
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Должно каждые 30мин сохранятся данные в файл data.data и забираться от туда на вывод. Проблема в том что при очередном заходе на страницу файл обновляется заново. Время создания файла изменяется, на текущее, а должно это происходить не раньше чем через 30 минут после последнего обновления. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обеспечения большей производительности при использовании функции filemtime() (и некоторых других) PHP кеширует результаты их выполнения.
Попробуйте очистить кеш файловой системы с помощью функции `clearstatcache();` перед вызовом `filemtime($cache_file_data)`.

Comment: Вот так? <?php
$cache_ttl = 1800; // время жизни кэша в секундах
$cache_file_data = "tmp/data.data";clearstatcache();
if (file_exists($cache_file_data) && (time() - filemtime($cache_file_data)) < $cache_ttl) {
    // берём кэшированные данные

Comment: да, можно и так.

Comment: Спасибо большое